# Auto JSDoc generation in Visual Studio Code broken?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, jsdoc

I'm doing TypeScript development, and recently updated to Visual Studio Code version 1.10.2. One thing advertised in this release is [auto generation of JSDoc comments](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_10#_auto-jsdoc-comments), where just by typing `/**` and RETURN in front of a JavaScript or TypeScript function you'll get a JSDoc comment block with customized placeholders for the functions's arguments. Very cool, and very useful.

However, this doesn't work for me. Type the `/**`, and I get the closing `*/`, but nothing else, even after typing that RETURN. Even stranger, I swear that this USED to work for me. It's possible that it was an extension doing this, but the only relevant extension I'd had installed was [Document This](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=joelday.docthis), and that must be triggered by a hotkey. I tried reinstalling Document This, but to no avail: I still don't get that lovely auto-generation. I've also looked through the settings, but didn't find anything relevant. I've also tried this under OS X 10.10.5, and Windows 10; same result.

Is this functionality working for other people? Any suggestion on how I could enable it, or debug/fix the problem?

Comment: Experiencing same issue with 1.13.1. I'm the only one in the office with this problem out of a half dozen people using VSC. Did you ever figure out what it was?

Comment: No, I dropped the ball. One problem is that I have the "Document This" extension installed, and I'm not sure whether it or VSC is doing the job. In any case, sometimes it works for me, and sometimes not; I haven't figured out a pattern.

Comment: Best I can tell. VSC is overriding the behavior of other JSDoc plugins. Disabling jsDocCompletion.enabled doesn't seem to affect this. I noticed that the built-in JSDoc autocompletion works for `function foo(bar)` but not for `this.foo=function(bar)`. For now I'm just manually typing our JSDocs. Ugh.

Answer (score 3):

I implemented auto jsdoc completion in VSCode.

If you are seeing an issue with this feature and it is not caused by extensions—i.e. it repos with all extensions disabled—please open a new github issue: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/new Include some sample code along with a brief set of repo steps so that someone can investigate what may be going wrong.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks (now **that's** service), and I'll do so. But, do you have any guess as to what might be going wrong? E.g., might this be caused by using an older (2.0.10) version of TypeScript?

Comment: Possibly but I can't say for sure without more info. The latest TS versions have a number of important bugs fixes. You may be running into a bug that TS 2.2 has already addressed